# Assembly- Parser : Instruction expected trying to emit a 128-bit integer constant

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am new to assembly language. I am using **NASM** assembler. Below is the code which I am working on.

```
  1 bits 64
  2 
  3 section .text
  4 global _start
  5 
  6 _start:
  7     
  8     mov rax, qword [dquad1]
  9     mov rdx, qword [dquad1+8]
 10     
 11     add rax, qword [dquad2+8]
 12     adc rdx, qword [dquad2+8]
 13     
 14     mov qword [dqSum], rax
 15     mov qword [dqSum+8], rdx
 16     
 17 _exit:
 18     
 19     xor rax, rax
 20     mov al,60
 21     mov dil,0
 22     syscall  
 23     
 24     
 25 section .data
 26     dquad1: ddq 0x1A000000000000000
 27     dquad2: ddq 0x1A000000000000000
 28     dqSum:  ddq 0x0
```

I get the following error when I assemble the code.

```
addwithcarry.nasm:26: error: parser: instruction expected
addwithcarry.nasm:27: error: parser: instruction expected
addwithcarry.nasm:28: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Kindly let me know how to solve the issue. The system is 64bit and I would like to add two 128bit values using `adc` instruction.

Thank You.

Comment: There is no `ddq` directive.

Comment: @Jester is there any alternative for ddq in NASM?

Comment: Store the two halves separately using `dq`, e.g. `dq 0xA000000000000000, 1`

Comment: @Jester when declaring `dq` as `dq 0xA000000000000000, 1` what does **, 1** refer to?

Comment: The top 64 bits.

Comment: @Jester i made the following changes in the code 
`26     dquad11: dq 0x1A000000000000000, 1` and now I get the following error
`addwithcarry.nasm:26: warning: numeric constant 0x1A000000000000000 does not fit in 64 bits`

Comment: Yes, that's because you did not split off the top 64 bits, like I have done.

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much for helping me understand